# Google Sign-in is not working

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I tried to use Google Sign-in for my website, however, it keeps giving me 400 error.

I referenced this article: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in, and my code is really simple:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Google Login</title>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="<CHANGE IT>">
  <script>
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click Sign-in button, it popups a window, and after logged in, it gave me 400 error as below:

```
400. That’s an error.

The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

I guess it's redirect issue, but I don't know how to configure it. So I checked url it returned to me:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?fetch_basic_profile=true&scope=email+profile+openid&response_type=permission&e=3100087&redirect_uri=storagerelay://http/127.0.0.1:8000?id%3Dauth867179&ss_domain=http://127.0.0.1:8000&client_id=378468243311-9dt7m9ufa9mee305j1b12815put5betb.apps.googleusercontent.com&openid.realm&hl=en&from_login=1&as=1b5f0a407ea58e11&pli=1&authuser=0
```

Why is redirect_uri "storagerelay://http/127.0.0.1:8000?id%3Dauth867179"?

Comment: Having the same problem, was about to ask the exakt same question.

Comment: One thing to note is that you should use https for your redirect uri. But that didn't help me. I also tried doing this on a server that can be accessed from Google, i.e. not localhost, but that didn't matter either.

Comment: @skagedal How to set redirect URI, cannot find a parameter for this

Comment: In the Developer Console. https://console.developers.google.com/ Did you create your Client ID here?

Comment: Or does your actual code say "<CHANGE IT>"?

Comment: @skagedal Sure I created my id

Comment: I am having this exact problem and nothing I've found resolves it.

The documentation for adding a client ID says that the Javascript APIs don't use a redirect URI, however a redirect URI is added to the URL when I click the Google Sign In button. I can't figure out how to get rid of it. I tried adding redirect URIs to the developer console for 127.0.0.1 but it made no difference. Ugh....

Answer (score 3):

Redirect URIs

```
http://localhost:8000/      this **/** at end solve my problem
```

JavaScript origins

```
http://localhost:8000
```

**NOTE: localhost and 127.0.0.1 conflicts can create problems for you sometime**

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work now.

Google fixed this issue. Origins with a trailing slash are also accepted now (Origin can be set in Google Developers Console > APIs & auth > Credentials).

Answer (score 1):

Hi I faced exactly same problem.

Regarding my case, the problem is that OAuth try to redirect to url of "127.0.0.1?id=authxxxxx" where xxxxx is random 5 digits.

Thus I added following four urls at Redirect URI Google Developers Console.
I am not sure which one hits the rule, but I could workaround with this 
(1) http://127.0.0.1/* 
(2) https of (1) 
(3) http://127.0.0.1
(4) https of (3)

Hope it also works for you.

Comment: Currently you should remove "Redirect URIs" from Console -> Credentials. Also, you should use "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 1):

To test on localhost environment, here's things we should to do:

1. Add "http://localhost:8000" to "JavaScript origins"
2. Remove everything from "Redirect URIs", because JavaScript API doesn't need any redirect URIs

[1] https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having the same problem, and was able to get past it by using "localhost" instead of the ip address. It's not a great solution, but it was sufficient for me to continue debugging in dev, so I just thought I'd mention it.

edit: keep in mind that you will have to add http://localhost to your Google Oauth Javascript Origins.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday. I had OAuth credentials with `localhost` and `my-server.com`. So, I fixed this problem creating a new OAuth credentials only for `my-server.com`, without `localhost`. Obviusly, my app uses these new credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that error disappears after clearing ACCOUNT_CHOOSER accounts.google.com cookie.

Comment: This also worked for me, nearly 8 years later.

Answer (score 0):

Replace everywhere`http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to `HTTP://localhost:8000/`even in your browser too. The Problem comes when you use `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` either in the developer console or a browser.