# google sign-in Storagerelay URI is not allowed for &#39;NATIVE&#39; client type

Tags: javascript, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I have been trying this simple google sign-in by following this tutorials:

- https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/
- http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-google-account-using-javascript/

The code is very simple and I'm exactly following the same steps as given in these tutorials, but I end up in the below error.

---

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_request

Storagerelay URI is not allowed for &#39;NATIVE&#39; client type
```

> [image: Storagerelay URI is not allowed for 'NATIVE']

In my credentials I have the configuration like below:

> [image: credentials configuration]

**My Code goes like below:**

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="377345478968-2opk94iompa38gja0stu1vi821lr3rt0.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>

<div id="gSignIn"></div>


function onSuccess(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v2', function () {
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
            'userId': 'me'
        });
        //Display the user details
        request.execute(function (resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        });
    });
}
function onFailure(error) {
    alert(error);
}
function renderButton() {
    gapi.signin2.render('gSignIn', {
        'scope': 'profile email',
        'width': 240,
        'height': 50,
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess': onSuccess,
        'onfailure': onFailure
    });
}
function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        $('.userContent').html('');
        $('#gSignIn').slideDown('slow');
    });
}
```

Every time when I click "Sign in with Google" button, new pop-up opens and 400 error throws up.

I also tried growing throw these answers in stackoverflow, but now luck.

1. [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)
2. [Google Sign-in is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201763/google-sign-in-is-not-working)

My Basic idea is to integrate sign in with google for my web-app, as said in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_31hJtWjlw), let me know whether this approach is good.

Comment: have u found the answer?

Comment: @SibeliusSeraphini nope :(

Comment: I've found the problem, you are using a clientId from a native device (ios/android), you should we one for the web instead. Try to create a new one if needed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because you haven't set up your OAuth 2.0 credentials for a Web Application. You may have specified the application type as "Other" when creating the credentials. I was facing the exactly same problem but then I changed my OAuth 2.0 credentials to a Web Application, and now it's working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot verify as I moved to other project. Accepting the answer coz you tried it out.

Comment: Could @Harshit edit his answer to make it less vague, i'm still lost..

Comment: @RaphaelSt I've just edited the response with what I believe is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered but in my case, while developing a desktop app with Electron and React, I had set the OAuth2 credential type as "Desktop". Changing it to "Web application" solved it for me.